# How to download .CMPcbdoc and .CMSchdoc file from Altium CircuitMaker onto computer

Tags: pcb, altium, circuitmaker

On Altium CircuitMaker, all the project files are stored in some online server. I want to download specifically the .CMSchdoc and .CMPcbdoc them onto my laptop for local storage. Is this possible? If so, what's the procedure for this?

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).